# Python match and replace, what I do wrong?

Tags: python, regex

I have reg exp for match some data (is it [here](https://regex101.com/r/yI0zC0/1)) and now I try to replace all matched data with single `:` characetr

```
test_str = u"THERE IS MY DATA"
p = re.compile(ur'[a-z]+([\n].*?<\/div>[\n ]+<div class="large-3 small-3 columns">[\n ]+)[a-z]+', re.M|re.I|re.SE) 
print re.sub(p, r':/1',test_str)
```

I try it on few other way but it's not replace any or replace not only matched but whole pattern

Comment: What does `/1` mean? Remove it if you need to [replace the matched data with just one `:`](https://regex101.com/r/tR3bW9/1). However, when manipulating HTML, you'd be safer  using an HTML parser.

Comment: Also notice that regex101 has a substitution section that would have let you spot the error easily.

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1250422) and the answers below it for very good reasons why you should **not** be doing this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `/1` it's mean 'first matched group?' I find it somewhere with google, when I remove it then replace work bu replace not one group in `()` but whole pattern. What HTML parser for python you have in mind?

Comment: @MastaBot: I worked with BeautifulSoup only, and can recommend it.

Comment: @Archimaredes I try to understand that text I read it twice but I don't see any reason why I should't use regex or my english is too bad, sorry

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'll give it try, thanks

Comment: Sorry @MastaBot, that post is mostly a joke - but its point is entirely serious. It is impossible to handle HTML entirely using regular expressions, so use a parser. :)

Comment: @Archimaredes sitll don't understand why it is impossible? Now i know that probably there is better tools for it than regexp but for sure it is still doable with regex

Comment: Okay, I'll admit it; 'impossible' is maybe too far. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105/1250422) is a good read.

Answer (score 0):

1)It's backslash issue.
Use : `print re.sub(p, r':\1',test_str)` not `print re.sub(p, r':/1',test_str)` .
2)You are replacing all the pattern with `:\1`, that means replace all the text with `:` followed by the first group in the regex.
To replace just the first group inside the text you should add two groups , before the first and after.
I hope this will fix the issue:

```
test_str = u"THERE IS MY DATA" 
p = re.compile(ur'([a-z]+)([\n].*?<\/div>[\n ]+<div class="large-3 small-3 columns">[\n ]+)([a-z]+)', re.M|re.I|re.SE) 
print re.sub(p, r'\1:\2\3',test_str)
```

Comment: you have right, anyway after I corret this, it replace but whole pattern not only matched part `()`